# I can't connect to the internet

Tags: server, internet, connection

i'm newbie on ubuntu.I have a problem that i can't connect to the internet.But the wireless network are working good.

The main problem is i have internet connection but when i open up firefox its say `Server not found` , `Firefox can't find the server at.start.ubuntu.com.`

I use dualboot Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.04.On my windows 7,the connection are just fine.Please help me, i cant wait to explore Ubuntu without any internet connection.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: You try to connect wireless or another connection type?

Comment: What does `ifconfig` output from the terminal's $-prompt? Add the output to your question. Also copy the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reviewing your wireless connection settings:

System Settings -> Network and there you could add your network name.  You probably will need to define the security key to have access from Firefox.